# Andorid App is not fecthing the location automatically

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I have converted a Website's page(https://taxif.com/online.html) to an Android App by using WebView. **The website automatically fetches the current location but the app is not fetching the current location**.

Please let me know how can I auto fetch the current location in webview same as in the webpage.

**MainActivity.java *File***

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebSettings;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.Toast;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;
    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
        refreshLayout = findViewById(R.id.refresh);

        refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
            public void onRefresh() {
                webView.reload();
            }
        });

        webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
        webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);


        webView.setWebChromeClient(new MyChromeClient());
        webView.setWebViewClient(new BrowserClient(refreshLayout));

        WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webSettings.setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);

        webSettings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
        webSettings.setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK);
        webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.setScrollBarStyle(View.SCROLLBARS_INSIDE_OVERLAY);
        webSettings.setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NARROW_COLUMNS);
        webSettings.setSavePassword(true);
        webSettings.setSaveFormData(true);
        webSettings.setEnableSmoothTransition(true);

        loadWebPage();

    }

    private void loadWebPage() {

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) MainActivity.this
                .getApplication().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if(networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()){
            webView.loadUrl("https://taxif.com/online.html");
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"You don't have any active internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

**BrowserClient.java *File***

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.webkit.WebResourceError;
import android.webkit.WebResourceRequest;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

import androidx.swiperefreshlayout.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout;

public class BrowserClient extends WebViewClient {

    SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout;

    public BrowserClient(){

    }

    public BrowserClient(SwipeRefreshLayout refreshLayout) {
        this.refreshLayout = refreshLayout;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceivedError(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request, WebResourceError error) {
        super.onReceivedError(view, request, error);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
        super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        refreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.xml *File***

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.booking">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.BookingApp">

        <!--
               Set to true if your app is Standalone, that is, it does not require the handheld
               app to run.
        -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
            android:value="true" />

        <activity
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="Booking App"><intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter></activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

***Thanks in Advance***

Comment: Did you ask runtime permission on Android 6+(API 23+) devices?

Answer (score 0):

in android, you need to write the code to get the user location,
this can be done on the "onPageStarted()" method, just check the url for the page that usses the location and if true, ask the user permission and get the device location.
something like below:

```
@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
    super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    if(url.equals(locationRequiredUrl) {
    getUserPermission();
    getUserLocation();
    }
    refreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
}
```